Sound cuts off on browsers in 24.04
I recently got a new laptop and it came pre-installed with windows, and there were no issues with sound. Then I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and sometimes, typically every hour or 2, the sound will cut off on my internet browser (Chrome, Brave and Firefox), and the only way to fix it straight away is closing it down and re-opening. If I leave it long enough and come back though, it often resolves itself. I haven't noticed sound issues with other apps, but i hardly use any others, so it's hard to say. Has anyone else had this issue, and managed to fix it?

Can you share more information about the hardware?

run ''alsamixer'' from term &unmute
